# Setting up demo ethereum PoA

Tags: parity, proof-of-authority, configuration

I'm new to ethereum/parity and trying to follow [this PoA setup demo](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Proof-of-Authority-Chains) as part of a larger project.

I've done it locally on my laptop, accessing resources via `localhost`. Now I'm trying to set up two separate nodes on two azure virtual machines and make them interact via internet.

Now my **first question** is - is this a sensible thing to do in the first place? Maybe I didn't grasp the architecture and these nodes shouldn't be exposed to the internet?

If this should work, I have the following problem - even a single node doesn't start properly.
I use [docker container ethcore/parity:stable](https://hub.docker.com/r/ethcore/parity/), this is my `node0.toml` file

```
[parity]
chain = "demo-spec.json"
base_path = "/tmp/parity0"
[network]
port = 30300
[rpc]
interface = "172.17.0.2"
hosts = ["172.17.0.2", "azure-vm-public-ip", "10.0.0.4"]
port = 8540
apis = ["web3", "eth", "net", "personal", "parity", "parity_set", "traces", "rpc", "parity_accounts"]
[ui]
interface = "172.17.0.2"
port = 8180
[dapps]
cors = "all"
hosts = ["azure-vm-public-ip", "10.0.0.4", "172.17.0.2"]
interface = "172.17.0.2"
port = 8080
```

I've added `hosts` and `interface`s to the original file from demo (link above). Here `azure-vm-public-ip` is the IP I use to connect to the vm from my laptop.
`10.0.0.4` is vm's local IP from `$ ifconfig` and `172.17.0.2` is IP that's seen from inside the docker container if you run `$ifconfig`.

`demo-spec.json` is exactly the same as in demo.

I run docker via this command, exposing all ports:

```
sudo docker run -ti --rm -p 30300:30300 -p 8080:8080 -p 8180:8180 -p 8540:8540 -v ~/demo-spec.json:/build/demo-spec.json -v ~/node0.toml:/build/node0.toml 65de5e38cf4b --config node0.toml
```

after startup public node URL is returned: `enode://...@172.17.0.2:30300`
which has docker's IP in it, not machine's IP and if I try to connect to http://azure-public-ip:8180/ from laptop I get

```
URL BLOCKED
YOU ARE NOT ALLOWED TO ACCESS TRUSTED SIGNER USING THIS URL.
Use: http://172.17.0.2:8180
```

and `Blocked connection to Signer API from untrusted origin` is written in parity log.

If I make a second connection to the vm and run `$ curl http://172.17.0.2:8180` a proper html is returned, but `$ curl http://localhost:8180` gives the same error.

If I change interface to `10.0.0.4` or `azure-public-ip`, parity doesn't start with the following error: `RPC io error: Cannot assign requested address (os error 99)`

So there seems to be a network setup misconfiguration, but I can't figure out where it is. Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

You need to map the external/public IP of your VM to its internal interface.

You can use `curl ifconfig.co` or `curl -4 http://l2.io/ip` to get the external ip of your machine and set it for your session
`sudo ifconfig eth0:0 $(curl ifconfig.co) up`

be sure that you don't have `--ui-no-validation` option. Here's a reference https://github.com/paritytech/parity/issues/5522

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, you're using two internal ip spaces. They will not talk to each other unless its on the same network. You should bind the public ip or replace the interface with interface star.star.star.star which will bind to all ip's on the host.

You can test once you restart by trying telnet to the port. Also, where you have azure-public-ip, use the actual ip vs the hostname.

Comment: Could you explain in more details how can I bind a public ip?